# How to detect SQL Hosted CLR at runtime

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr

I would like to detect that my assembly is loaded in SQL Hosted CLR at runtime in order to safely process the AppDomain FriendlyName string.

Unfortunately, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainManager.EntryAssembly` is `null` in this context.

Any help appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: Doesn't that observation anwer your own question?

Comment: No. At this time I've no idea if this behavior would actually exhibit with other applications hosting the CLR.

Comment: @omatrot I am pretty sure that SQL Server is the only other host for the CLR, outside of the Windows OS (at least, if there are others, I believe it is the only one to have any Host Protection Attributes defined). Still, did you see the answer from @spgennard? It is the correct way for determining whether or not the code is running inside of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I use `SqlContext.IsAvailable` to determine if I am running under the SQLCLR... it works a treat..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlcontext.isavailable.aspx

Comment: This is the best, if not only, way to determine if the code is running inside of SQL Server or not, AFAIK.